# iOS Swift Storing GPS coordinates into array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, gps, core-location

I have following question:

I'm working on iOS app which is used by inspectors to inspect parts of the roads. When they are outside for inspection, the app has functionality to track the route that have driven. When driving for long time e.g 4-5 hours the app crashes. To store whole route I'm using an array where I store each coordinate. Is it possible that the array is getting too big and exceed memory limit?

I will be glad if someone give me an advice. Thanks

Comment: You might want to add a little more details about like a part of your code or more specific conditions. your question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't store all the location points in memory. You need to design a buffer to store temporary locations and then save to a persistent store (Like CoreData, SQLite, or even a .gpx file if you prefer) on every N locations (up to you how often you store location points).

I also suggest taking a close look at what should the accuracy of your location manager be. More accuracy means more data and more battery usage.

You should also consider filtering location points and only store meaningful locations! (ex. if someone is just standing somewhere, you don't want to record duplicate locations, which won't be exactly the same in coordinates, but are very close to each other.)